# jquery update item count on click when fetching ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have created a ajax load more button to grab more data from my database, which all works fine. I am now trying to do a count, so the button displays how many results are left to display. Here is my jQuery code that is fired when the button is clicked:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
        var ID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        var count = jQuery(".singleproduct").length;
        var totals = jQuery('.totalleft').text();
        var finaltotal = totals - count;
        //jQuery('.show_more').hide();
        jQuery('.loding').show();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            async: true,
            crossDomain : true,
            url:'example.com/data.php',
            data:'count='+count,
            success:function(html){
            //jQuery('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
              jQuery('.retailitems').append(html);
              jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery(".site-info").offset().top}, 1000);

            }
        }); 
        jQuery( ".totalleft" ).replaceWith( finaltotal );           
    });
});
```

And here is the code for the button:

```
<span id="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" class="show_more" title="Load more posts">Load <span class="totalleft"><?php echo $loadmore;?></span> more</span>
```

When clicked for the first time, the button updates with the correct remaining results. When clicked a second time, the news results populate, but the count remains the same.

Do i have things in the right order above?

Thanks

**EDIT**

So i found the issue. The calculations were correct, but when updating the count on the button i was actually removing the class of 'totalleft' with this:

```
jQuery( ".totalleft" ).replaceWith( finaltotal );
```

So i replaced this with:

```
jQuery( ".totalleft" ).text( finaltotal );
```

and all is fine, thanks for all the help.

Comment: Hey, did you console.log(finaltotal) to verify it differ each time or not?

Answer (score 1):

parse the `text()` in `.totalleft` to get an integer value

```
var totals = parseInt(jQuery('.totalleft').text());
```

if your calculations are correct, you should get the right number back

**EDIT**

because `ajax` is `async` you are re-updating the value of `.totalleft` before the `ajax` is complete.

make sure that you are doing that in the `ajax` callback:

```
success:function(html){
   //jQuery('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
   jQuery('.retailitems').append(html);
   jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery(".site-info").offset().top}, 1000);

   jQuery( ".totalleft" ).replaceWith( finaltotal );
}
```

finally, I'm not sure what `var count = jQuery(".singleproduct").length;` is so make sure that the values you are expecting are correct by console logging before and after the subtraction

**EDIT #2**

```
var count = jQuery(`.singleproduct`).length;
console.log('count :' + count);
var totals = jQuery('.totalleft').text();
console.log('totals :' + totals);
```

are you getting numbers on the above logs? if not, then you might be replacing some part of your html with the `ajax` request and `singleproduct` or `totalleft` may not be there anymore

Comment: Hey, i have just tried this but still getting the same results. Any ideas?

Comment: @danyo - check my edited answer. to be sure that your math is correct, console log the values before and after the subtraction. I'm not sure what         `var count = jQuery(".singleproduct").length;` is supposed to be

Comment: count = 10; i have just console logged the results. in total there are 38 items, so after the first click the log shows 28, and then i get "NaN"

Comment: @danyo - can you update your question to include the `.singleproduct` element? is it in a part that stays unaffected by the `ajax` request?

Comment: Yes, this is just a fairly standard loop which isnt affected

Comment: @danyo - there are no ghosts in javascript :), check my **Edit #2** to make sure that `singleproduct` and `totalleft` are still there when you click